# Multiple change target event is not triggering in VBA (ByVal Target As Range)

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to format cells in different rows one with number and another with date using VBA . My code is as below. But the second event is not getting triggered. When I interchange the 1s and 2nd event up to down (date first and number second), date format works and number doesn't works. Can I get any help here please?

```
*Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   
'___________ 8 DIGITS FORMAT ____________________
   
   
Dim i As Integer
Dim cell As Integer
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo Err 'To avoid error when multiple cells are selected
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("U:U")) Is Nothing Or _
       Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) And Target.Value <> "" Then
cell = Target.Rows.Count
    
For i = 1 To cell
'To avoid cells with NO VALUE to be FORMATTED
If Target.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
Target.Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
Target.Cells(i, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Target.Cells(i, 1).Value, "00000000")
Else
Resume LetsContinue
End If
Next i
End If
    
Application.EnableEvents = True
    
'______________________ Date Format ____________________
   
   
Dim x As Integer
Dim dt As Integer
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo Err2 'To avoid error when multiple cells are selected
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Or _
       Not Intersect(Target, Range("AQ:AQ")) And Target.Value <> "" Then
dt = Target.Rows.Count
    
    
For x = 1 To dt
'To avoid cells with NO VALUE to be FORMATTED
If Target.Cells(x, 1).Value <> "" Then
Target.Cells(x, 1).NumberFormat = "dd-Mmm-yyyy"
Target.Cells(x, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Target.Cells(x, 1).Value, "dd-Mmm-yyyy")
Else
Resume LetsContinue
End If
Next x
Else
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Err:
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("U:U")) Is Nothing Or Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    Resume Next
    Else
    Resume LetsContinue
    End If
Err2:
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Or Not Intersect(Target, Range("AQ:AQ")) Is Nothing Then
    Resume Next
    Else
    Resume LetsContinue
    End If
    
 
LetsContinue:
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
    
    
Whoa:
    
    Resume LetsContinue
    
  
    End Sub*
```

Answer (score 0):

### A Worksheet Change: Formats and Values in Multiple Columns

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim irg As Range
    
    ' 8 digits
    
    Set rg = RefColumns(Me, 2, "B,U")
    Set irg = Intersect(rg, Target)
    
    If Not irg Is Nothing Then
        Format8Digits irg
        Set irg = Nothing
    End If
    
    ' Dates
    
    Set rg = RefColumns(Me, 2, "E,AQ")
    Set irg = Intersect(rg, Target)

    If Not irg Is Nothing Then
        FormatDates irg
        Set irg = Nothing
    End If

End Sub


Function RefColumns( _
    ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
    ByVal FirstRow As Long, _
    ByVal ColumnsList As String, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ",") _
As Range
    
    Dim Cols() As String: Cols = Split(ColumnsList, ",")
    Dim rResize As Long: rResize = ws.Rows.Count - FirstRow + 1
    
    Dim trg As Range
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(Cols)
        Set rg = ws.Cells(FirstRow, Cols(n)).Resize(rResize)
        If trg Is Nothing Then Set trg = rg Else Set trg = Union(trg, rg)
    Next n
    
    Set RefColumns = trg

End Function

Sub Format8Digits(ByVal rg As Range)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In rg.Cells
        If Len(CStr(Cell.Value)) > 0 Then
            Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
            Cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction _
                .Text(Cell.Value, "00000000")
        End If
    Next Cell
    
SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub

Sub FormatDates(ByVal rg As Range)
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In rg.Cells
        If IsDate(Cell) Then
            Cell.NumberFormat = "dd-Mmm-yyyy"
            Cell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction _
                .Text(Cell.Value, "dd-Mmm-yyyy")
        End If
    Next Cell
    
SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this query after 2 months.

In the first event when we give Resume LetsContinue which actually ends the code, 2nd event should be triggered for which 2nd and subsequent events should be given defined with names and Resume "Events" in 1st event.

Here is how it should be:

```
Resume Event2
End If
Next i
End If
    
Application.EnableEvents = True
    
'______________________ Date Format ____________________
   
Event2:
   
Dim x As Integer
Dim dt As Integer
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo Err2 'To avoid error when multiple cells are selected
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Or _
       Not Intersect(Target, Range("AQ:AQ")) And Target.Value <> "" Then
dt = Target.Rows.Count
```

And the code continues----------------